# asset_path in Rails 4 is producing unhashed asset paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I've got a Rails 4.0.3 application, and I've got a pretty simple image tag:

```
<%= image_tag('logo_big.png') %>
```

When in development, this works as expected and everything is happy. However, in production, the tag still links to the unhashed version of the image:

```
<img alt="Logo big" src="/z/logo_big.png">
```

It should be appending the hash to the filename, in this case resulting in "logo_big-21d3b1db0a8536f5717646dfea417791.png". Using asset_path directly also does not work. Javascript and CSS file links all work correctly and append the hash as normal.

So why is it not including the hash?

Additional info / confounding factors:

- I've got an alternate assets prefix ("asset" is a resource in my application), which is "z"
- I'm using Sass 3.2.19 (sass-rails 4.0.2)
- I'm using Compass 0.12.5 (compass-rails 1.1.6)
- Hashing works for images in every template, *except* for layout templates.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the z directory to your assets path in application.rb?

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/z"
```

Also check out whether this is in production.rb:

`config.assets.digest = true`

Comment: config.assets.digest is set to true.

When I say "alternate assets directory", I mean the prefix it is being served out of, not the directory in which it is stored locally. I'm using


    config.assets.prefix = '/z'

Answer (score 0):

Try precompiling your assets before pushing to production:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
git commit -a -m "Precompile for release"
git push
git push heroku master
```

This should fix things up for you.

For more info, check out: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

**Update**

Here's another article that could help:

https://medium.com/self-directed-learning/9ba1f595102a

Flipping on this configuration in Heroku made some of my asset pipeline problems go away:

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a yourapp
```

Comment: Assets are already precompiled. They're compiled with the hash in the filename. The problem is that `image_tag`/`asset_path` aren't referring to the hashed versions of the files.

Comment: I'm not using Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `config.assets.css_compressor = :sass` is enabled in production.rb